# Xamarin IOS Fly Out Navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using this Fly Out Navigation for IOS and I want to add a image and text on the Navigation at the top how could I do this?

Something think like this https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu where it says A title but i replace that one with a image and text how would i do that with Clancey Fly Out Navigation

```
https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation
```

Edit: this is what i have tried

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    var navigation = new FlyoutNavigationController {
        // Create the navigation menu
        NavigationRoot = new RootElement ("Navigation") {
MonkeyImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("PurpleMonkey"); // This is what i tried adding here but it does not seen to work
            new Section ("Pages") {
                new StringElement ("Animals"),
                new StringElement ("Vegetables"),
                new StringElement ("Minerals"),
            }
        },
        // Supply view controllers corresponding to menu items:
        ViewControllers = new [] {
            new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Animals (drag right)" } },
            new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Vegetables (drag right)" } },
            new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Minerals (drag right)" } },
        },
    };
```

Comment: You need to provide examples of what you have tried.

Comment: @valdetero Added some code

Answer (score 0):

Use "ImageElement" to add image to your FlyOut.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
```

{

```
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    var navigation = new FlyoutNavigationController {
        // Create the navigation menu
        NavigationRoot = new RootElement ("Navigation") {
MonkeyImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("PurpleMonkey"); // This is what i tried adding here but it does not seen to work
                new Section ("") {
                new ImageElement (UIImage.FromBundle ("PurpleMonkey")),
            },
                new Section ("Pages") {
                new StringElement ("Animals"),
                new StringElement ("Vegetables"),
                new StringElement ("Minerals"),
            }
        },
        // Supply view controllers corresponding to menu items:
        ViewControllers = new [] {
            new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Animals (drag right)" } },
            new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Vegetables (drag right)" } },
            new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Minerals (drag right)" } },
        },
    };
```